# How to use Cypress to stub useSession and getSession in Next.js with next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress, sinon, stub

I'm trying to stub with Cypress both the frontend and backend calls to `useSession()` and `getSession()` respectively.

The stubbed functions don't seem to replace the functions or get called:

[image]

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
const client = require("next-auth/react")
....
....
cy.stub(client, "getSession").returns({
  user: {
    name: "xxx",
    email: "xxx",
    image: "xxx",
  },
  expires: "2022-07-08T09:49:47.602Z",
})
cy.stub(client, "useSession").returns({
  user: {
    name: "xxx",
    email: "xxx",
    image: "xxx",
  },
  expires: "2022-07-08T09:49:47.602Z",
})
cy.visit(`/draft/cl45ip2d600379as17epvu6ti`)
```

I've tried googling it but most people seem to use jest for this and not cypress and there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation and I'm not sure how to continue.

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but the call to getSession is being triggered by a client http request to the api.

Comment: did you ever get it working? I'm just starting with Cypress and I'm looking at what's the best way to start a test with an authenticated user set up, using Next.js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `cy.stub(useSession, 'prototype').returns('my_value')`

The following test could print the console warn in my chrome console as it executed :

```
import React from 'react'
import FormCreationConcession from './FormCreationConcession'
import TEST_TYPES from '@/Constants/tests-types'
import {useSession, SessionProvider} from 'next-auth/react'
import {testLocators} from '@/Constants/testLocators'

// https://medium.com/geekculture/component-testing-next-js-application-with-cypress-28fa311adda6
describe(`${TEST_TYPES.component.integration} <FormCreationConcession /> works correctly for professionnal site user`, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // see: https://on.cypress.io/mounting-react
    cy.mount(
      <SessionProvider session={{}}>
        <FormCreationConcession />
      </SessionProvider>
    )

    cy.stub(useSession, 'prototype').returns(console.warn('testttt'))
  })

  it('findByTestId', () => {
    cy.findByTestId(testLocators.components.FormCreationConcession.title)
  })
})
```

A bit of reading of https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub and then analyzing how I could manipulate a function, which is a type of object by doing `// console.log('useSession : ', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(useSession))` helped me to find out.

Comment: Update: it only controls the output of the cy.stub() but does not replace what useSession does. The useSession is still executed.

Comment: You can also intercept the '/auth' calls on the Nextjs api by mocking the api with miragejs. By default, cypress will use 'localhost:8080/api' for the Nextjs server.



`export const createMockNextApi = params => {
  params = {environment: params?.environment ?? 'test'}

  const {environment} = params

  return createServer({
    environment,

    routes() {
      this.urlPrefix = 'http://localhost:8080'
      this.namespace = 'api'
      this.get('**auth**', () => {})
      this.passthrough('http://external-api.com')
    },
  })
}`

https://miragejs.com/